# Converting latitude, longitude to image coordinates

Tags: latitude-longitude, interpolation

I have a 2D image and I know a given pixel in the image corresponds to a particular latitude longitude (so basically a reference point). The image I have is a camera image of an outdoor scene and I have the possibility to identify the (lat, long) of some of the points on that camera scene.

How could one transform a given latitude, longitude to a pixel coordinates given this information. I am guessing just one reference point is not enough and perhaps we need at last two to establish the spatial resolution. Is that sufficient information to transform latitude, longitude to image coordinates.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html

Comment: This is georeferencing, and in order for it to work halfway decent you need three identical points widely spread over the image.

Comment: If you know the exact image size, orientation and have one point you can calculate the top left coordinate. It is then possible to save the image as a raster using GDAL   .https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html

Comment: To clarify, the image I have is a camera image of a scene (so not a map) and all I can do is identify some poiints with their corresponding lat, long coordinates and basically would like to interpolate/estimate lat/long for any pixel from this information

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: @Luca, with a camera image you are likely to have some perspective in your image and that will impact georeferencing accuracy. It depends on the image and your end goal whether this would be an issue.

Comment: @IanTurton Thank you. Sorry if I broke the rules. I will update with some detailed question.